# how to write superscripts before symbols in equation mode in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I know that using caret you could do this after the symbol but what is the way to do it for having a superscript before a letter? if there is a shortcut for this id appreciate if you let me know that as well. thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Try ^(superscript) space, then the letter that will have the superscript.  Typing ^2 X gives:

[image]

EDIT:  How to get rid of the square?

Click on the square to select it and type a space.  There doesn't seem to be an option in Word's equation editor to have only a leading superscript - you have to have both a super- and subscript and then make one invisible.  For *trailing* super- and subscripts, all options are available.  Here are the available combinations:

[image]

Comment: then how to get rid of the square?

Comment: @user750737, if you found this helpful, please see [this help topic](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Thank you. That helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
(_a^b)Z_c^d
```

This is the complete form which will (on pressing space at the end) result in:
<sup>a</sup><sub>b</sub>Z<sup>d</sup><sub>c</sub>

You can eliminate any of the _? or ^? to remove that superscript/subscript and no box remains.

Answer (score -1):

As suggested by Bandersnatch (sorry, I do not know how to @somebody), you can use the lift sub/superscripts for typing left superscript, to eliminate the subscript box visually, you just type space in it. Same for having left subscript.

Cheers

Comment: Are you adding something to Bandersnatch’s answer, or just paraphrasing it?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.